# Dash line between curly brackets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I add something like this with an extension, or by another way in VS Code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd> >>

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Answer (score 4):

This should now be natively supported with VBSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021, 4 years later)

> ### [Bracket guides](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/6410254c0429000dc8a8402e1ae41e6dbffc22a8/release-notes/v1_61.md#bracket-guides)
>
> **The editor now supports rudimentary bracket pair guides**.
>
> Bracket pair guides use the same colors and the same algorithms as the bracket pair colorization feature.
> Similar to indentation guides, the active bracket pair guide is highlighted.
>
> [image: Bracket pair guides shown in the editor -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_61/bracket-pair-guides.png]
>
> Bracket pair guides can be enabled by configuring the `editor.guides.bracketPairs` setting (defaults to false).
> We will continue iterating on this feature and explore vertical guides in the next release.

---

With VSCode 1.62 (Oct. 2021), you also have:

> ### [Improved bracket pair guides](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d4a1f43b568ae04331a8ca861c0e1b2fba5d19db/release-notes/v1_62.md#improved-bracket-pair-guides)
>
> We continued iterating on bracket pair guides.
>
> - Horizontal lines now outline the scope of a bracket pair.
> - Also, vertical lines now depend on the indentation of the code that is surrounded by the bracket pair.
>
> [image: Bracket pair horizontal lines moving with text indentation]
>
> Bracket pair guides can be enabled by setting editor.guides.bracketPairs to true (defaults to false). We added a third option "active" to only show a bracket pair guide for the active bracket pair.
>
> The new setting editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal controls if and when to render horizontal guides (defaults to active).
>
> New themable colors editorBracketPairGuide.background{1,...,6} and editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground{1,...,6} can be used to customize the color of bracket pair guides.

See [PR 134259](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/134259).

---

VSCode 1.67 (Apr. 2022) even comes with ***horizontal* guides** within bracket pairs on the same line

Instead of:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31039318/140437032-8582746f-35a0-41a0-a8d3-7ae3b4479ce9.png]

You get:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31039318/140437301-19e238b5-d520-49cc-b858-6c6ec92d8d77.png]

Comment: There are new options and a new horizontal look for bracket pair guides, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/134259

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about enabling those indent guides in your VScode editor.

First is going to the settings and setting an option called
 "editor.renderWhitespace" to "true".

The second is installing an extension called "Guides". The extension takes a bit of configuring but you have more customization than what the method above provides. https://github.com/spywhere/vscode-guides

Comment: "editor.renderWhitespace": "all" - not what i asked, but 'Guides' works perfect, thank you